# Is there a way to figure out what's wrong?

Tags: python, file, encoding, spyder

I wrote those codes and they were running just fine, and gives the correct answers, but suddenly they began to give me wrong answers or get to next code directly, I don't know what happened?
when entering city correctly, tells me to choose from available! and in month: the month is written correct but still not in months and also with days???!

```
enter code here
print('Hello! Let\'s explore some US bikeshare data!')
# get user input for city (chicago, new york city, washington). HINT: Use a while loop to handle invalid inputs
cities = ['chicago', 'new york', 'washington']
city = input('Choose a city: \n >').lower()

if city not in cities:
    city = input('Choose from available Cities: Chicago, New York or Washington: \n >').lower()

    
if city == 'new york':
        city = 'new york city'

    
# get user input for month (all, january, february, ... , june)
months = ['all', 'January', 'Feburary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June']
month = input('Please select month or for all months type "all": \n >').lower()

if month not in months:
    month = 'all'
    print("This month is not available so it's gonna be all")

# get user input for day of week (all, monday, tuesday, ... sunday)
days = ['all', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
day = input('Please Choose specific day or for all days type "all": \n >')

if day not in days:
    day = 'all'
    print("That day isn't available, so it's gonna be all")
```

Comment: There is probably a blank character, use `strip()` on the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
month = input('Please select month or for all months type "all": \n >')
```

remove the lower() else change the elements in months list to lowercase.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it solved your problem. The elements in your months list are in Capitalised case while you are taking input in var month as lower case.

Comment: Thank you, that was right, but I still need to make it work with the upper case.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was to make the variables in the lists in lower case
it worked now
but still don't know how it was working before with the upper case just like I posted.